# Unable to declare Kind type for Kubernetes API Type Declarations

Tags: go, kubernetes

I'm relatively new to golang and need some help pointing to the right direction.

I'm trying to declare a new `Deployment` type.

My imports look like:

```
import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  yaml "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
  "io/ioutil"
  metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
  "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/v1"
  "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/extensions/v1beta1"
)
```

When I try to create a Deployment Object like:

```
  test := v1beta1.Deployment{
    Spec: v1beta1.DeploymentSpec{
      Template: v1.PodTemplateSpec{
        Spec: v1.PodSpec{
          Containers: []v1.Container{{
            Name:  "test",
            Image: "image_url",
          },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }
```

It works, but the Deployment Object that returns doesn't have a `Kind` which is necessary to identify the object.

According to https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/apis/extensions/types.go#L162

There's an embedded `metav1.TypeMeta` which has the `Kind` object that I need. (For reference: https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/blob/master/pkg/apis/meta/v1/types.go#L38)

I tried declaring `metav1.TypeMeta` in the struct literal like:

```
  test := v1beta1.Deployment{
    metav1.TypeMeta: metav1.TypeMeta{Kind: "Deployment"}
    Spec: v1beta1.DeploymentSpec{
      Template: v1.PodTemplateSpec{
        Spec: v1.PodSpec{
          Containers: []v1.Container{{
            Name:  "test",
            Image: "image_url",
          },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }
```

But I get a

`unknown field '"k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1".TypeMeta' in struct literal of type v1beta1.Deployment`

I suspect it is due to `metav1.TypeMeta` declaration in the `Deployment` struct is an unexported field.

How should I declare Kind?

Answer (score 2):

When using an embedded struct, the key is usually the type name without the package. You can declare your `TypeMeta` like this:

```
test := v1beta1.Deployment{
  TypeMeta: metav1.TypeMeta{
    APIVersion: "apps/v1beta1",
    Kind: "Deployment",
  },
}
```

However, manually setting the `TypeMeta` on any Kubernetes API object is usually only necessary if you plan to persist these objects yourself (for example, to generate YAML files).

When using the Kubernetes client API (for example, using the k8s.io/client-go package) to talk to an API server, you will not need the `TypeMeta` property, since all API operations are strongly typed anyway and all metadata can safely be inferred. After all, the API version and kind of a `v1beta1.Deployment` struct should be (and are, to the client library) obvious.

Comment: I am using client-go to fetch a resource and need to use the "Kind" for some switch decision, but Kind is empty in the retrieved object. What is the best way to solve this?